# Macro script to copy matching column values in two open excel

Tags: excel, vba

i've a macro script to identify the matching column value in two open excel(Column A in first excel and column A in second excel) . I need matching column values to be copied to new excel(third excel) in column A. Please guide me.

```
Sub Compare()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range
Dim sBook As String

If Workbooks.Count < 2 Then
  MsgBox "Error: Only one Workbook is open" & vbCr & _
 "Open a 2nd Workbook and run this macro again."
  Exit Sub
End If

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
For Each wb2 In Workbooks
 If wb2.Name <> wb1.Name Then Exit For
Next

On Error Resume Next
ReDo1:
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
sBook = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
"Compare this workbook (" & wb1.Name & _
") to...?", _
Title:="Compare to what workbook?", _
Default:=wb2.Name, _
Type:=2)
If sBook = "False" Then Exit Sub
  If Workbooks(sBook) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Workbook: " & sBook & " is not open."
    GoTo ReDo1
   Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks(sBook)
   End If

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each ws1 In wb1.Sheets
 If Not wb2.Sheets(ws1.Name) Is Nothing Then
   Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(ws1.Name)
   For Each Cell In ws1.UsedRange
    If Cell.Formula = ws2.Range(Cell.Address).Formula Then
      Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
      ws2.Range(Cell.Address). _
      Interior.ColorIndex = 35
    End If
  Next Cell
  If ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count = _
   ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count Or _
  ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count = _
  ws2.UsedRange.Columns.Count Then
  For Each Cell In ws2.UsedRange
   If Cell.Formula = ws1.Range(Cell.Address).Formula Then
     Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
     ws1.Range(Cell.Address). _
     Interior.ColorIndex = 35
   End If
   Next Cell
   End If
   End If
   Next ws1

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VBA was real good and got you quite close.  I would recommend adding these variables.

```
Dim wb3 As Workbook
Dim wb3cell As Range
```

From there, the 1st line opens a new workbook and assigns it to wb3.  You also want to assign a *Range* variable to cell A1 in wb3 to send your results to.

```
Set wb3 = Workbooks.Add
Set wb3cell = wb3.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
```

After your line *ws2.Range(Cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 35*, these next 2 lines transfer the match over to wb3.  You already found it to change the background, so it's most efficient to send that value to wb3 at that time.

```
wb3cell.Value = Cell.Value
Set wb3cell = wb3cell.Offset(1, 0)
```

This last bit of code is yours, and I noticed it finding the same results as the loop above.  Maybe it should be removed or changed from *If* to *ElseIf* to match up with your *If Not wb2.Sheets(ws1.Name) Is Nothing Then* line or maybe it's fine the way it is.  I only mention it because it gave me duplicate results, but that could just be the "play data" I created that's doing it.

```
If ws1.UsedRange.Rows.count = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.count Or _
ws1.UsedRange.Columns.count = ws2.UsedRange.Columns.count Then
    For Each Cell In ws2.UsedRange
        If Cell.Formula = ws1.Range(Cell.Address).Formula Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
            ws1.Range(Cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
            wb3cell.Value = Cell.Value
            Set wb3cell = wb3cell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next Cell
End If
```

Comment: The last two lines code (MaxRow), just copies the entier column of ws2. It doesn't not copy the matching vlaue's to column A(Ws3).Like the unmatched value should be removed and matched value should be in sequence.

Comment: Is there a way to copy the cell with particular color ? In my case this will also solve the issue, as in new excel ws3 , the matching value will be in green color(ColorIndex = 35).so the cell with green color will be copied to new excel (ws4) in a sequence. Please help.

Comment: I streamlined my answer.  I was able to use a simpler approach than I originally thought this needed.